# How can I use acknowledgment semantics in a Flow?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'd like to design a flow which will only pull from upstream when an `ActorRef` receives some acknowledgment message.

My use case is to use some static clustered actors to do work. I have a guardian which maintains whether or not there are available workers. When an actor becomes available, it will publish a message. I would like my Flow to be aware of this message to pull a job and push it downstream. Otherwise, it will backpressure.

When reading the docs, the `GraphStage` API doesn't seem to have some reactive component, relying on `InHandler`s for custom processing:

```
setHandler(in, new InHandler {
  override def onPush(): Unit = {
    println(grab(in))
    pull(in)
  }
})
```

I could potentially poll in this method for an update on the number of available actors, but this is not reactive.

Does Akka support acknowledgment in Flows by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Push Not Pull**

Instead of having the stream signal demand upstream once an `Actor` is free you could have the `Source` send data instead.

You can create a Source that will materialize into an `ActorRef` which will be notified of a free Actor:

```
object ActorIsFreeMessage

val source : Source[ActorIsFreeMessage, ActorRef] = Source.actorRef(???, ???)
```

You can then attach a `Flow` which will "pull a job" once the Source receives the message:

```
type Job = ???

val pullAJob : () => Job = ???

val jobFlow : Flow[ActorIsFreeMessage, Job] = 
  Flow[ActorIsFreeMessage].map[Job](_ => pullAJob())

val jobSource : Source[Job, ActorRef] = source via jobFlow
```

Once this new Source is attached to a Sink the other Actors can send messages to the materialized `ActorRef`:

```
val jobSink : Sink[Job, ActorRef] = ???

val streamRef = jobSource.to(jobSink).run()

//inside of the Actor
streamRef ! ActorIsFreeMessage
```

Comment: Ah, I think I would have to create the pull logic separately; i.e., I cannot integrate this with an existing `Source`?

Comment: I think this also reduces to polling: if that from which I'm pulling is empty, I must necessarily poll from it, too, right?

Comment: @erip I didn't realize that you don't have discretion around the `Source`.  I will have to modify my answer accordingly.  In terms of polling: you could make your `pullJob` function blocking if no `Job` is available yet.

Comment: I am flexible, I just wanted to make sure I understood correctly. I'm using Alpakka connectors to a legacy MQ-based system, so it'll need some work -- if I can continue using Alpakka, that would be nice. :-)

Comment: Upon further reading, I think using [`akka.stream.scaladsl.Zip`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-cookbook.html#triggering-the-flow-of-elements-programmatically) on the two sources (the trigger source and the Alpakka source) should be good! This was a good recommendation -- thanks again.